# Issue with making autocomplete script with xml file

Tags: jquery, xml, autocomplete, redirect

I am trying to make a site search for my site, so that user can search some page with typing some words and they are redirected to the corresponding url of myDomain. I am trying to make an autocomplete for that where I am using help of an xml file for fast speed instead of mysql database. I have put all the titles of my webpages and the corresponding urls in that xml file. Following are my piece of codes.

My HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>..</title>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myArr = [];

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "categories.xml", // change to full path of file on server
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseXml,
            complete: setupAC,
            failure: function(data) {
                alert("XML File could not be found");
                }
        });

        function parseXml(xml)
        {
            //find every query value
            $(xml).find("category").each(function()
            {
                myArr.push($(this).attr("label"), $(this).attr("url"));

            }); 
        }

        function setupAC() {
            $("input#searchBox").autocomplete({
                    source: myArr,
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        $("input#searchBox").val(ui.item.value);
                        window.location = ui.item.value


                    }
            });
        }
    });
</script>

<!-- Code for Search Box -->

<div id="header-search">
 <span class="font-select">
  <b>Search Page by Typing few charaters:</b>
    <form name="search_form" id="searchForm" method="GET" action="#">
    <input type="text"  id="searchBox" name="searchString" placeholder="Type category to search.."/>
    </form>
    </span>     
    </div>
....
</body>
</html>
```

And following is my content of XML File "categories.xml" :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<categories>
<category label="AC and Refrigeration" url="url_1.php" />
<category label="Advertising Agencies"  url="url_2.php" />
<category label="Aluminum and Fabricator" url="url_3.php" />
<category label="Architects" url="url_4.php" />
<category label="Arm and Ammunition" url="url_5.php" />
<category label="Acupressure and Acupuncture Clinic" url="url_6.php" />
<category label="Astrologers" url="url_7.php" />
<category label="ATM Booths" url="url_8.php" />
<category label="Auto Agency" url="url_9.php" />
</categories>
```

Now, by using above pieces of codes and xml file, my autocomplete functionality is working very fine i.e. if I type the few characters of category labels (mentioned in xml file), it is showing me the autocomplete options to select in search box.

But the problem is when I finally select any one option, it redirects me to the url which is same word which is selected in search box i.e.the category label word in xml file , but i want to redirect it to corresponding  url to the value of url in xml file.

e.g. if I have selected the first option "AC and Refrigeration", it is presently redirecting me to url "myDomain.com/AC and Refrigeration" but I want it should redirect me to corresponding url value of xml file i.e. "myDomain.com/url_1.php" . So please look into this code and help me to achieve this as I have tried many things but not able to achieve this, I am missing some small thing here near "window.location = ui.item.value" in script or somewhere else.
Thanks in advance - please help me with the changes or addition in my piece of code.
Please help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `myArr.push($(this).attr("label"), $(this).attr("url"))` you're pushing into `myArr` both the `label` and `url` as elements of your array. (If you were to type `url` in your input it would return `url_1.php` ...).
You need to add an object containing both the label and url :

```
myArr.push({label: $(this).attr("label"), url : $(this).attr("url")});
```

You could then access the item value with `ui.item.label` and `ui.item.url` and your redirect would look like this :

```
$("input#searchBox").val(ui.item.url);
window.location = ui.item.url
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Neksu.... it is working now as I wanted. I got your point where I was mistaken. Thanks for this great help...!